# asp.net: treeview - show textbox if checked?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i need to display a list of strings to a user. the user can select multiple strings. if a specific set of strings is selected a textbox will appear next to each string.

what i want to do is show the user a TREEVIEW with each node being one of the strings. they will select every string they want by checking the box.

**the problem:**
if the user selects specific checkboxes i need a textbox to appear to GET input from the user.

**question**: how do i get string input from the user with a treeview?

Comment: I don't get it.Is that mentioned treeview the only thing on the webpage?I mean why don't you just place it somewhere else?Also, I think ListView would fit better for this job or even a ListBox.

Comment: @AteşGÜRAL: thanks for suggestion but would it be possible for user to edit?

Comment: Well, you can use that textbox(the one which is going to appear).even if that textbox is for something else you can use a constant textbox which gets the selectedItem of the ListBox when the listbox's selecteditem changed then write what you want and click a button and save it.I am doing this in a part of my project.I think TreeView is created for categorized data that is why I suggest ListBox or ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TreeView does not support including TextBoxes natively.  You could use a JavaScript solution where you create client side text boxes and serialize the value mapping to an `<asp:HiddenField />`.

Set up your TreeView and HiddenField:

```
<asp:TreeView runat="server"
    ID="MyTreeView"
    ShowCheckBoxes="All"
    NodeStyle-CssClass="node">
    ...
</asp:TreeView>
<asp:Hidden runat="server" ID="TreeViewTextValues" />
```

Some jQuery:

```
$(".node :checkbox").click(function (e) {
    var node = $(this).closest(".node");
    if (this.checked) {
        $("<input/>").addClass("nodeTextBox").appendTo(node);
    }
    else {
        node.find("input.nodeTextBox").remove();
    }
});
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    var nodeText = $("input.nodeTextBox").map(function () {
        return encodeURIComponent(this.value);
    });
    $("input[type=hidden][id$=TreeViewTextValues]").val(nodeText.join("&"));
});
```

Some C#:

```
var text = TreeViewTextValues.Value.Split('&').Select(s => Server.UrlDecode(s));
// text.ElementAt(n) maps to MyTreeView.CheckedNodes[n]
```

Untested, but hopefully a helpful start.